# How to save qml ui as pdf

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5

I have created one ui in qml, now i want to save that ui as pdf. I tried using **GrabWidow** but in my qml I am using more than 2 application windows. Grab window taking my main qml as screenshot but i want to take my second application window .

```cpp
void PdfExporter::screenShot(QString path, QString winid)
{

    foreach(QObject* obj, mEngine->rootObjects()) 
    {
        QQuickWindow* window = qobject_cast<QQuickWindow*>(obj);
        qDebug()<<"window Name:" << winid;
        if (window)
        {
            window->renderTargetId();
            QImage image = window->grabWindow();

            QPrinter printer;
            printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
            printer.setOutputFileName(path+"/Report.pdf");

            QPainter painter(&printer);
            printer.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
            QRect rect=painter.viewport();
            QSize size=image.size();

            size.scale(rect.size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
            painter.setViewport(rect.x(), rect.y(), size.width(), size.height());
            painter.setWindow(image.rect());

            //painter.drawImage(0,0,100,100,image);
            painter.drawImage(QRect(0, 0, image.width(), image.height()), image);

             //painter.begin(&printer);

        }
    }
}
```

How can i specify which window needs to be grabbed using grab window

Comment: Are you sure your code isn't already working but just overwriting the second window output with the first given you always use the same file name?

Comment: could you please elaborate in detail.

Comment: Try using a different file name for each window here: `printer.setOutputFileName(path+"/Report.pdf")`.

Comment: Hi, i can able to save the pdf but it's saving my main qml as a pdf, i have 2 qml file main and report qml and creating component of report qml in mani. i want the report qml as pdf not main

Answer (score 1):

Your code works, but you override the already existing file.
In the line below you set a static file `Report.pdf` so the printer will always print to this file, which will and override it.

```cpp
printer.setOutputFileName(path+"/Report.pdf");
```

I suggest you utilize the `winid` to specify what windows you are printing.
You can achieve this by altering the above line to the following:

```cpp
printer.setOutputFileName(path + "/"  + winid.toStdString() + "_Report.pdf");
```

This will give you a file for each window you are trying to print.